# Cant Access Kibana URL: This Kibana installation has strict security requirements enabled that your current browser does not meet

Tags: kibana, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks

am not able to access kibana from browser. getting the below error when i do curl to kibana. kibana is accessed via ingress controller.

curl xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/app/kibana

```
<div class="kibanaWelcomeLogo"></div></div></div><h2 class="kibanaWelcomeTitle">Please upgrade your browser</h2><div class="kibanaWelcomeText">This Kibana installation has strict security requirements enabled that your current browser does not meet.</div></div><script>
            // Since this is an unsafe inline script, this code will not run
            // in browsers that support content security policy(CSP). This is
            // intentional as we check for the existence of __kbnCspNotEnforced__ in
            // bootstrap.
            window.__kbnCspNotEnforced__ = true;
          </script><script src="/bundles/app/kibana/bootstrap.js"></script></body></html>root@10:~/EK/work#
```

kibana ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: logging-od
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /app/kibana
        backend:
          serviceName: logging-kibana
          servicePort: 5601
```

using kubectl proxy forward to kibana service works without any issues

```
kubectl -n logging port-forward svc/kibana --address 0.0.0.0 8088:5601
```

looked at ingress controller logs but it goes through fine.

```
10.224.91.15 - - [04/Mar/2021:05:12:35 +0000] "GET /app/kibana HTTP/1.1" 200 75425 "-" "curl/7.47.0" 152 0.019 [logging-od-logging-kibana-5601] [] 100.64.131.52:5601 75425 0.016 200 429c46c4006caefa2a160018cca3195d
```

any idea

Comment: The error you're seeing in `cURL` is a red herring; that's due to the `Content-Security-Policy` header used by Kibana.  I would look at your ingress controller logs and see if there is a meaningful error there.

Comment: yes, you are right. some issue appears to be with content security policy. but no error is seen in ingress controller logs. it shows the call went through with status code 200

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Kibana pod logs?  What about in the ingress controller logs if you hit it with a browser rather than cURL?

Comment: No errors in kibana pods. It runs fine

Answer (score 3):

Go to conf/kibana.yml, and try to set csp.strict: false

But make sure this is not done with production instance

Comment: then what should be done for  production instance?

Comment: I'm having this issue, where Chrome through a VPN and Chrome on a random Windows instance on a laptop are both blocked due to the CSP handling. Do you have any idea what the issue is? This seems buggy, given no other applications raise this concern.